# Has Buddha Gautama ever had problems with some autorities about his teachings and way of live?

Tags: the-buddha

I thougt that Siddarta Gautama lived in a Hindu society. But were there Brahmans who disagreed with Siddartha or was Siddartha ever in an argue with them?

Comment: Is your question about Brahmans (religious authorities), or is it about civil authorities (e.g. kings or police etc.)? Because I think that there were several arguments with Brahmans recorded in the suttas, but I don't remember his having problems with civil authorities.

Comment: Primairly with the Brahmans but I think that because of the unity of state and religion the civil autorities would be interesting too.

Comment: i'm totally not sure about 'the unity of state and religion' in the ancient India of the Buddha's days... the picture which transpires from the suttas is of religious and philosophical pluralism... the fact that kings and officials frequented Buddha shows that they weren't bound by or had to be loyal to certain creed

Answer (score 2):

> I thougt that Siddarta Gautama lived in a Hindu society

As far as you mean he lived in India, immersed in India culture of the time, yes. But as far as `hindu` refers to an India majoritarily submsersed in the Vedic tradition, it's not clear this is so.

The period of the Buddha and early Buddhism is marked by a variety of religious movements known as *sramanas* (which included Buddhists and Jains, for example, among many others). So there was already a culture that rejected the vedic traditions of the time. Also, the geography seems to be of a region with many individual states and kingdoms, not of a "single India". I'm not sure if these states were, largely, supporters of brahmins or not (and if they were, it was soon in decline with the rise of the empires -- from the Nanda empire which seems to have supported the Jains, through the Maurian empire, when the emperor Ashoka converted and supported Buddhism).

> But were there Brahmans who disagreed with Siddartha or was Siddartha ever in an argue with them?

Buddha disagreed not only with Brahmins, but with all the other *sramanas* whose teachings were not in agreement with the Buddha's teachings. These encounters, philosophical disputes and criticisms are massively documented in the buddhist canon.

> Has Buddha Gautama ever had problems with some authorities about his teachings and way of live?

I don't remember the Buddha ever been in legal trouble, though sometimes kings came to him to solve some issue involving the sangha.